# Knit PDF produced PDF different than Source in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

When I `knit PDF` on  RStudio. It DOES NOT match what is in my Rmd file after `source` of the `.Rmd`. This has happened every time I tried to `Knit PDF`. How can I get example what is in my `.Rmd` into `Knit PDF`? I've tried clearing cache and restarting RStudio but this inconsistency is still happening...

Comment: You don't normally call `source()` on an Rmd file.  That's for pure R code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `set.seed()` at instance where you are generating random data if you are generating any.

1. Try to clean your environment and rerun and assess results
2. Try to `set.seed` at the top of the code and rerun.